# Multiple plots on the same figure julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I am writing a Julia program which iteratively runs another function, and will give me two sets of results. I want to plot these results and right now what I am doing is to plot the results of each `for` loop separately which gives me about 20 plots for the example below:  Say something like this:

```
for i in 1:10
    x1,y1 = first_function(a,b,c)
    plot(x1,y1)
end
for j in 1:10
    x2,y2 = second_function(a,b,c)
    plot(x2,y2)
end
```

I have tried to use the `plot!()` command instead but this gives me all 20 plots on the same plot, which I don't want. What I would like to do is to plot the results of both functions on the same plot, for each iteration. For instance I want 10 plots, one for each iteration where each plot has results of both `first_function()` as well as `second_function`. I have tried the following instead:

```
for j in 1:10
    x1,y1 = first_function(a,b,c)
    x2,y2 = second_function(a,b,c)
    plot!(x1,y1)
    plot!(x2,y2)
end
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either.

EDIT: Based on an answer I received, I was able to figure out that the following does the trick:

```
for i in 1:10
    x1,y1 = first_function(a,b,c)
    x2,y2 = second_function(a,b,c)
    plot(x1,y1)
    plot!(x2,y2)
end
```

This generates a new plot at the end of each iteration of the loop, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have found out, `plot()` creates a new plot, while `plot!()` plots onto the currently active plot.

All you need to do is be explicit about when you want to do what, and if you're using `plot!()` also be explicit about which plot object you want to plot to. So something like:

```
p1 = plot()
p2 = plot()

for i in 1:10
    plot!(p1, first_function(a, b, c)...)
    plot!(p2, second_function(a, b, c)...)
end
```

then `p1` should have 10 lines showing the result of `first_function`, and `p2` 10 lines with results of the second function.

It is not clear to me whether you want both of these plots to appear on the same figure, but if you do then `plot(p1, p2)` will create a figure with two subplots.

Comment: I wanted the first iteration of both functions in one plot, second iterations for both in a different plot and so on, with a total of 10 plots (in this case). So this isn't exactly what I wanted. However, based on what you said I did try something else instead which I've mentioned as an edit to my post, and that seems to work. 
Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear and sorry for not reading properly - you clearly said you wanted 10 plots! You might have figured this out already but just for posterity if you actually want to see the plots at every loop iteration you have to `display` them, as the loop won't return the plot object.

Comment: Yes, I did realise that and added `display`. Thanks!

Comment: Given the question is basically answered now, it might be good to just accept my answer to close it, even though the final answer is in your question!